# Routing DSL modem to web server

Tags: router, web-hosting, d-link, adsl

I am using "D-LINK DSL-2520U ADSL2+ ETHERNET/USB COMBO ROUTER" broadband modem.

I hosted a web site using a web server in my PC (port 80).

When I tried to access my external IP from my mobile, it took me to the DSL router admin screen.

I tried to change the port of DSL routers admin screen to some other port, but i couldn't find any such option.

I saw there is a virtual server option under "Advanced Setup --> NAT --> Virtual Servers" which basically used to allow incoming request from particular port to connected computer. I setup this to forward to my PC, but still i am getting the same DSL router admin screen.

anybody used this router earlier and configured successfully?

```
Device Info
Board ID:   DSL-2520U
Software Version:   IM_1.00
Software Date:  Jun 11 2010
Bootloader (CFE) Version:   before 1.0.37-5.12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added my webserver IP in the DMZ host setting "Advanced setup -> NAT -> DMZ Host" and redirected the request to the mentioned IP. Now i am able to access my web server over internet.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right path with the Virtual Server setup. You need to take a closer look at your settings, and make sure Router Administration is disabled for the WAN port. It may be named something else, but you should see somewhere that blocks external access to the routers webconfig.

Just to make sure though, are you testing from an external source? It's possible that you may see the routers admin panel, but other users are properly directed to the server.